# Count total number of pages printed using Canon LBP 2900B printer

Tags: laser-printer, windows-vista

I have a Canon model LBP2900B. I would like to know how many pages I have printed using this printer.

I'm using Windows Vista Home Premium.  I have connected to this printer through the USB Port, so I could not find it via IP Scanning or Net View.

Answer (score 1):

When you fire a print through Canon LBP2900B printer, dialog box opens on the screen. Select Options->Utility->Configure Page Print. Select 'OK' to print page configuration. In the print out, you will see the total pages printed.